# Connection between jQuery and HTML

Tags: jquery, html

There are two files, html and jquery. I want to know if possible to connect between these two files.

jquery-test.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#inputForm').submit(function(){
        $('#inputForm :text:not("#submit")').each(function(){
            var input = $(this).val();
            var someData = [];
            var weblink = 'http://www.google.com&callback=?'; // just example
            $.getJSON(weblink, function(data){
                $.each(data.results, function(i, item){
                    someData.push(item.json_Tag);
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

and the HTML file is below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv = "Content-Type" content = "text/html">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method = "post" action = "/result" id = inputForm>
            <input type = "text" name = "input" id = input>
            <input type = "submit" value = "Search" id = search>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The process is below:

1. User key in some word in the text area and press button.
2. The jquery will link to "weblink" and catch some data.
3. jQuery return these data to HTML file.
4. HTML file redirect to /result page with these data.

But I don't know how can I do the process above ? I don't know how to return the data form jquery ? I don't know how to let HTML redirect to  other page with data .

Thank you very much.

Comment: This sounds like a standard POST to me?

Comment: There is a post method in jquery. But there are a litter different with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript (and jQuery, in this case) is designed to run in the user's browser. You deliver the Javascript to the user by including it in the HTML page.

Include the following in the HEAD section of your HTML document:

```
<script src="jquery-test.js'></script>
```

Correct your HTML by adding double quotes around the text "inputForm" and all of the other HTML attributes

```
<form method="post" action="/result" id="inputForm">
```

The jQuery code will now be executed when the user submits the form with ID "inputForm".

Comment: Actually, I I already include the jQuery in the HTML file (line 5). But I still don't know how to return data which is in jQuery to HTML. and I don't know how to let the HTML redirect to other with these data.

Comment: I don't even know what you're asking D:

Comment: Take a look at the part of your jQuery code that starts with "$.each(...". The Javascript engine will cycle through each of the results, and perform an action on each one. If you want to display the data in your HTML document, you can change the line "someData.push...". For example, to add the data to an HTML div with id "output_div", you can use $("#output_div").append(item.json_Tag).

Comment: Yes, you can show the results on the same HTML page using the method I described above.

Comment: If you want to show the information on a different page, you don't need the AJAX request (the "$.getJSON(weblink, function(data){..." part of your jQuery. Just do the processing in "/result" (which is already the target of your form submit), and output the results on that page.

Answer (score 1):

Can't your html file include a  section that contains your jquery logic?  Or, you can include a  reference in the top of your file, like this:

```
<script src="~/ScriptLocation/MyScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: In that case can you please outline the problems you are having. We can't answer a question that doesn't exist ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do would be done better with a server-side scripting language such as PHP

Like this:

- user enters data in your HTML form just as you have it
- user is redirected to /result page
- your server-side script can access the post data, query the 'weblink', and display the result.

If you want to use jquery you might find it easier/better to display the result on the same page. Why redirect if you do not have to?

---

OK if you really cannot use server-side scripts here are a couple things:

- It is not possible to retrieve post data using javascript. You could retrieve data from a get request by parsing the URL I think.
- An easier solution would be to display the data on the same page. you already have the JSON containing the data, so you can loop through it using something like the `$.each()` function in JQuery and display the contents however you'd like.

Comment: That's the original framework of my system. But there are some problem between the server and the third-party website. So I want to run the script on user side.